# InitialState setted but reducer not being executed. Reduce doesnt change store

Tags: typescript, redux, react-redux, action, reducers

I'm trying to integrate redux with my react native + typescript app.

From an specific component I'm dispatching an action:

```
export const setCurrentOrder = (order: PostOrderRequest) => async (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
    console.log('order in action: ', order);
    dispatch({
            type: MENU_POST_ORDER,
            order: order
    });
}
```

**That console.log is not being executed so do I have a mistake calling my action?**

This is how I'm calling setCurrentOrder from my component:

```
handleNext() {
        const {pizza} = this.state;
        const {navigation} = this.props;
        const currentOrder = {
            pizza
        }
        console.log('current order: ', currentOrder);
        setCurrentOrder(currentOrder);
        navigation.navigate('Login');
    }
```

handleNext() is being called on a button's onPress event.

Then my reducer:

```
const initialState: MenuState = {
    order: {pizza: []}
}

export default function (state = initialState, action: MenuAction) {
    console.log('REDUCER: ', action);
    switch (action.type) {
        case MENU_POST_ORDER:
            return {
                ...state, 
                order: action.order
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }   
}
```

By the way, that console.log inside the reducer function IS NOT BEING EXECUTED! I dont know why, but seems like the initialState is being setted but the reducer function is never executed.

I executed setCurrentOrder from a component. Then after doing that, the component route the user to other component. From that other component I'm using react-redux to get the state:

```
export default withNavigation(connect(
    state => ({
        state: state
    }),
    null
)(LoginScreen));
```

But when I log `this.props.state` its showing the initialState. I tried setting this.props.state to the component react state and using componentDidUpdate to check if the props change and if its, updating my react state. But its always showing my initialState so:

**Why initialState is being setted but the reducer function is not being executed?**

Edit:

This is how I'm dispatching setCurrentOrder from my component (the withNavigation wrapper is because I'm using react-native-navigation):

```
export default withNavigation(connect(
    null,
    (dispatch: Dispatch) => ({
        setCurrentOrder: (order: PostOrderRequest) => dispatch<any>(setCurrentOrder(order))
    })
)(MenuScreen));
```

Comment: You're not using `dispatch` in your `mapDispatchToProps`. Try changing it to `setCurrentOrder: (order: PostOrderRequest) => dispatch(setCurrentOrder(order))`.

Comment: I see. I've edited my post adding dispatch<any> (because Im using typescript). I've also edited my action because I don't have to return anything, I just have to dispatch the action. But the action is not being executed and really dont know why. I've also added how I'm calling the action from the component. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's a shame. Inside handleNext()

```
setCurrentOrder(currentOrder)
```

should be

```
this.props.setCurrentOrder(currentOrder)
```